# Unexplained listing alert

Tags: tokens, bsc, bscscan, algorithm, list

Sorry for the newbie question

But there are actually telegram channel which deliver listing alert seconds to minutes before the actual listing on CoinMarketCap and CoinGecko

They claim they dont work together with CMC and CGK
Meaning they made their algorithm to detect the upcoming listings

I actually interest in this matter, what kind of possible method did they use?
is it using solidity, bscscan or something?

Comment: Do you mean that how a transaction get notify on the telegram before it even on the blockchain?

Comment: Token which about to get listed to be exact

Comment: I don't think there is an algorithm for that maybe they just check for event calender on CoinMarketCap and notify the user before it release or maybe they have a team to check on crypto news and notify people